# Automatically archive knowledge in Lightning by date field

Tags: knowledge, archive

I created a field "Expected archival date", when reaching that date I need to archive the knowledge. I am trying to do for Batch but I am not able to implement, could you help me?
My Code:

```
global class ArquivarKnowledgeBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        string query = 'SELECT Id,KnowledgeArticleId,BR_PrevisaoArquivamento__c,PublishStatus FROM Solucoes__kav WHERE BR_PrevisaoArquivamento__c = Date.Today() AND PublishStatus=\'Online\'';
        System.debug('Select: '+ query);
         return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Solucoes__kav> archive) {
        system.debug('Artigos: '+ archive);
        for (Solucoes__kav know : archive)
        {
            KbManagement.PublishingService.archiveOnlineArticle(know.KnowledgeArticleId, null);
        }    
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        System.debug('ACABOU O BATCH');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to file it by validating the expected date with the code below

```
global class ArchiveKnowledgeBatch implements Database.Batchable <sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {
     global Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext BC) {
         Date todaysDate = system.today ();
         string query = 'SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId, BR_PrevisaoArquivamento__c, PublishStatus FROM Solucoes__kav WHERE BR_PrevisaoArquivamento__c =: todaysDate AND PublishStatus = \' Online \ '';
         System.debug ('Select:' + query);
          return Database.getQueryLocator (query);
     }
     global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, List <Solucoes__kav> archive) {
         system.debug ('Articles:' + archive);
         for (Solucoes__kav know: archive)
         {KbManagement.PublishingService.archiveOnlineArticle (know.KnowledgeArticleId, null);
         }
     }
     global void finish (Database.BatchableContext BC) {
         System.debug ('BATCH IS OVER');
     }
}
```

To make the Batch call, I created the Schedulable below:

```
global class ScheduleArquivarKnowledge implements Schedulable {
     global void execute (SchedulableContext sc) {
         Database.executeBatch (new FileKnowledgeBatch (), 150);
     }
}
```

And I scheduled to run 2 times a day